# How to we set focus to a specific date in ngx-bootstrap datepicker without populating it in Angular 11?

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I have a requirement to highlight a specific date in the date picker and then show the date upon expanding it without populating the datepicker. User should still be forced to pick the date themselves but these highlighted dates would be a useful reference to them. I'm using ngx-bootstrap 7.1.0, Angular 11, typescript 4.1.6.

I highlighted the date using dateCustomClasses so that part I was able to achieve. I couldn't find anything to move the focus of the calendar to the date being highlighted. The only options which came close were

1. bsValue - This populates the calendar too unfortunately
2. minValue - maxValue - This restricts the dates outside the specified range from being selected